# Why is a category/ tag name prefixed to title of every page?

Tags: title, wp-title

Recently, I've noticed there is a category/ tag name "Contests" added to the title of all of my pages.

I've checked the "Tagline" under "Settings" >> "General" of course, it hasn't changed.

This is what's in `header.php` and I have never touched it at all:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> </title>
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at your theme's header to see if anything is defined there (for example, what is passed to `wp_title`, if anything is concatinated to it either before or after, stuff like that)

Comment: Thanks @LeaCohen, I've edited and included what I have in header.php. I have never changed anything related to the page title though.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there's a plugin that has a filter that meddles with the title? Have you tried disabling plugins? Also, could you include a screenshot?

Comment: @LeaCohen, I'm suspecting the samething - some plugin must be guilty of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause.

All in one SEO Pack plugin 1.6.14.5 is guilty (perhaps it's not guilty by itself but also due to the multisite setup of my site and other plugins I've just installed conflicting it). Disabling the plugin resolve the problem immediately. I'm upgrading it and will use an alternative if it doesn't work out. Thanks @LeaCohen for pointing me to the right redirection.

**Updates**
Instead of deactivating the plugin, disabling the auto-rewrite title in settings of the plugin is sufficient.
At the same time, just FYI, All-in-one SEO Pack plugin version 1.6.13.8 works just fine for WordPress multisite 3.4.2. I can no claims about the possible conflicts between this and any other WordPress plugins